# How to map a subset of an API result to a class in an Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 6 project and am not sure how to map API results to a class

I have an API that returns results like the following

```
{
    "Id": "f400b615-9041-4e64-a7d1-ff04855b2d00",
    "fields": [
        {
            "cid": "auth0|5b3b0031297c9026b864fc6e",
            "name": "Field1",
            "questionText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        },
        {
            "cid": "auth0|5b3b0031297c9026b864fc6e",
            "name": "Field2",
            "questionText": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
        },
        // etc
```

There are up to 100 fields, and I'd like to generate a class from each of them.

I have the following class definition:

```
export class OpportunityField {
    fieldId = ""
    name = ""
    questionText = ""
}
```

How do I parse my API to get the fields related to 'Field2' and make that a new object that I can then pass to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actualy Interface should look like this, you can check with **[`JSON2TS`](http://json2ts.com/)**

```
export interface Field {
    cid: string;
    name: string;
    questionText: string;
}

export interface OpportunityField {
    Id: string;
    fields: Field[];
}
```

now you can access fields to using **`OpportunityField.fields[1].`**

Comment: That's helpful thanks, but the field 'Field2' map not be at .fields[1], I need to do a search through the whole object and only extract the one field I need...

Comment: in that case use let field = opportunitiy.fields(f=>f.name === "field2");